# Moble Internet via SIM Card on Laptop

Tags: laptop, mobile-workstation

I have a Acer R3-471T laptop running Windows 10 and would like to be able to have mobile data on it via a SIM card. Mi-Fi's, Mobile USB Dongles, etc. are not viable since my phone provider (Cricket, located in Maryland, USA) does not offer them.

Is there a device available to do this?

Comment: Why do you care about provider's offer? Isn't it possible to order it on your own? Could you specify your laptop's model? You must have an open miniPCI-E slot to install WWAN Card. It looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynMltgL4mNY

Comment: I cannot get anything other than a SIM card from Cricket so I must use one for my mobile connection. As stated in the question, my laptop is an Acer R3 running Windows 10.

Comment: I meant more specific info about the model ;). Something like "R3-471TG" etc... But if you don't have a miniPCI-E slot probably there's no way to install it inside your laptop. How about dedicated device such as http://www.amazon.com/Cricket-A600-USB-Broadband-Modem/dp/B001V7AYLG/? I don't know much about this provider but isn't it possible to buy second-hand modem like this?

Comment: As I said, I can only get a SIM card on my current plan. I edited the question with the full model number.